# include javascript Multiple files in wordpress through script.js

Tags: php, jquery, javascript

i have script.js file for html to wordpress conversion. In html it works, but in wordpress it does not work. This file contains slider, menus etc, I enable to convert html to wordpress without this file, the file has following contents

```
function include(scriptUrl) {
    document.write('<script src="' + scriptUrl + '"></script>');
}

function isIE() {
    var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
};

/* cookie.JS
 ========================================================*/
include('js/jquery.cookie.js');

/* Easing library
 ========================================================*/
include('js/jquery.easing.1.3.js');

/* Stick up menus
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('html');
    if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
        include('js/tmstickup.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#stuck_container').TMStickUp({})
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

/* ToTop
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('html');
    if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
        include('js/jquery.ui.totop.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $().UItoTop({
                easingType: 'easeOutQuart',
                containerClass: 'toTop fa fa-arrow-up'
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

/* EqualHeights
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('[data-equal-group]');
    if (o.length > 0) {
        include('js/jquery.equalheights.js');
    }
})(jQuery);

/* SMOOTH SCROLLIG
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('html');
    if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
        include('js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js');
        include('js/jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.min.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.srSmoothscroll({
                step: 150,
                speed: 800
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

/* Copyright Year
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#copyright-year").text((new Date).getFullYear());
    });
})(jQuery);


/* Superfish menus
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    include('js/superfish.js');    
})(jQuery);

/* Navbar
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    include('js/jquery.rd-navbar.js');
})(jQuery);

/* Camera
========================================================*/
;(function ($) {
var o = $('#camera');
    if (o.length > 0) {
        if (!(isIE() && (isIE() > 9))) {
            include('js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js');
        }

        include('js/camera.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            o.camera({
                autoAdvance: true,
                height: '25.8536%',
                minHeight: '300px',
                pagination: true,
                thumbnails: false,
                playPause: false,
                hover: false,
                loader: 'none',
                navigation: false,
                navigationHover: false,
                mobileNavHover: false,
                fx: 'simpleFade'
            })
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

/* FancyBox
========================================================*/
;(function ($) {
    var o = $('.thumb');
    if (o.length > 0) {
        include('js/jquery.fancybox.js');
        include('js/jquery.fancybox-media.js');
        include('js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js');
        $(document).ready(function () {
            o.fancybox();
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

/* Parallax 
=============================================*/ 
;(function ($) { 
    include('js/jquery.rd-parallax.js'); 
})(jQuery);


/* Google Map
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = document.getElementById("google-map");
    if (o) {
        include('//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false');
        include('js/jquery.rd-google-map.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var o = $('#google-map');
            if (o.length > 0) {
                var styleArray = [
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#2c2e33"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": 7
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 19
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "landscape",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#ffffff"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -100
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#ffffff"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -100
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 31
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 31
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road.arterial",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": -2
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road.local",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -90
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": -8
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "transit",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": 10
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 69
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -78
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 67
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]

                o.googleMap({
                    styles: styleArray,
                });
            }
        });
    }
})
(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    var o = document.getElementById("google-map2");
    if (o) {
        include('//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false');
        include('js/jquery.rd-google-map.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var o = $('#google-map2');
            if (o.length > 0) {
                var styleArray = [
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#2c2e33"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": 7
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 19
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "landscape",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#ffffff"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -100
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#ffffff"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -100
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 31
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 31
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road.arterial",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": -2
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road.local",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -90
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": -8
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "transit",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": 10
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 69
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -78
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 67
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]

                o.googleMap({
                    styles: styleArray,
                });
            }
        });
    }
})
(jQuery);

/* WOW
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('html');

    if ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') == -1 ) || (isIE() && isIE() > 9)) {
        if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
            include('js/wow.js');

            $(document).ready(function () {
                new WOW().init();
            });
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

/* Contact Form
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('#contact-form');
    if (o.length > 0) {
        include('js/modal.js');
        include('js/TMForm.js'); 

        if($('#contact-form .recaptcha').length > 0){
            include('../www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js');
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

/* Search.js
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    include('js/TMSearch.js');
})(jQuery);

/* Orientation tablet fix
 ========================================================*/
$(function () {
    // IPad/IPhone
    var viewportmeta = document.querySelector && document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]'),
        ua = navigator.userAgent,

        gestureStart = function () {
            viewportmeta.content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6, initial-scale=1.0";
        },

        scaleFix = function () {
            if (viewportmeta && /iPhone|iPad/.test(ua) && !/Opera Mini/.test(ua)) {
                viewportmeta.content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0";
                document.addEventListener("gesturestart", gestureStart, false);
            }
        };

    scaleFix();
    // Menu Android
    if (window.orientation != undefined) {
        var regM = /ipod|ipad|iphone/gi,
            result = ua.match(regM);
        if (!result) {
            $('.sf-menus li').each(function () {
                if ($(">ul", this)[0]) {
                    $(">a", this).toggle(
                        function () {
                            return false;
                        },
                        function () {
                            window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
                        }
                    );
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase(),
    regV = /ipod|ipad|iphone/gi,
    result = ua.match(regV),
    userScale = "";
if (!result) {
    userScale = ",user-scalable=0"
}
document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0' + userScale + '">');
```

i tried many methods. how should i include this to work in a wordpress in proper way?

Comment: How are you currently including the file?

Comment: <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/script.js"></script>

Comment: Is this a child or a parent theme? **What does your browsers error console say?** I also notice that your `include` function uses relative paths, you shouldn't be dynamically including javascript files like that, it's bad for performance, and those relative paths will make the browser load those files in different locations on different pages

Answer (score 0):

Open console ( right click -> inspect - Console ) and read what is the error, you probably didn't enqueue jQuery

You should enqueue scripts from **functions.php** ( best practice )

```
function theme_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array(), false, true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

Comment: i already done this but nothing could be happen

Comment: Any errors in console? You probably need to set up babel ( webpack ) for ES6 features ( like include() ) to work

Comment: @WPVlad Burhan is using a function defined at the top of the file that dynamically loads them in via `document.write`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a WP problem, this function is your problem, and the cause of a great many other problems you're unaware of:

```
function include(scriptUrl) {
    document.write('<script src="' + scriptUrl + '"></script>');
}

....

include('js/jquery.cookie.js');
```

This is bad practice, and error prone:

- Every time this happens, all rendering is paused while the browser fetches the remote script
- The browser is unable to preload the script to improve performance

But more importantly, the function expects a full URL, yet you're passing in relative URLs. This means every time you change page, the URLs the browser tries to load change too,

e.g. for `js/jquery.cookie.js`

- On the homepage `example.com/js/jquery.cookie.js`
- On `/about` it'll try to load `example.com/about/js/jquery.cookie.js`
- On `/test` it'll try to load `example.com/test/js/jquery.cookie.js`
- etc...

So absolute URLs need to be passed. But worse yet, there are performance issues, so instead of using the `include` function, do one of the following options:

- Register and enqueue all the libraries, if you have to selectively enqueue them, do the checks in PHP, not JS
- Bundle them all
- Use a modern JS toolchain and transpile them into a bundle using Babel and Webpack, this will let you use ES6 syntax and the `require` function

Again, this is not a WP problem, this is an issue with the original code that was always there, but now shows up because you moved the file into a different location on the server relative to the root

Additionally, you should look into your browsers developer tools. The JS console will be throwing 404 errors for all of those `include` calls saying the browser could not find the JS file, and the full URL it tried to find it at